# Returning to root on a SwiftUI NavigationStack from another view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm having the hardest time figuring out NavigationStacks in SwiftUI. I have a MVP example below from Apple's documentation on NavigationStack. What I would like to do is have a button that would all me to pop all the way back to the root if I select it instead of having to hit the back button a bunch of times if I'm multiple pages into it.

Can you please show me how to do this or tell me what I'm not understanding about the `NavigationStack` framework?

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Pushable stack
struct PushableStack: View {
    @State  var path: [Recipe] = []
    @StateObject  var dataModel = DataModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List(Category.allCases) { category in
                Section(category.localizedName) {
                    ForEach(dataModel.recipes(in: category)) { recipe in
                        NavigationLink(recipe.name, value: recipe)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Categories")
            .navigationDestination(for: Recipe.self) { recipe in
                RecipeDetail(recipe: recipe)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(dataModel)
    }
}

// Helpers for code example
struct RecipeDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var dataModel: DataModel
    var recipe: Recipe

    var body: some View {
        Text("Recipe details go here")
            .navigationTitle(recipe.name)
        ForEach(recipe.related.compactMap { dataModel[$0] }) { related in
            NavigationLink(related.name, value: related)
        }
        // I would like to have a Button here
//        Button(action: {
//            Go all the way back to the root
//        }) {
//            Text("Dummy Value 1")
//        }
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var recipes: [Recipe] = builtInRecipes

    func recipes(in category: Category?) -> [Recipe] {
        recipes
            .filter { $0.category == category }
            .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    }

    subscript(recipeId: Recipe.ID) -> Recipe? {
        // A real app would want to maintain an index from identifiers to
        // recipes.
        recipes.first { recipe in
            recipe.id == recipeId
        }
    }
}

enum Category: Int, Hashable, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case dessert
    case pancake
    case salad
    case sandwich

    var id: Int { rawValue }

    var localizedName: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch self {
        case .dessert:
            return "Dessert"
        case .pancake:
            return "Pancake"
        case .salad:
            return "Salad"
        case .sandwich:
            return "Sandwich"
        }
    }
}

struct Recipe: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var category: Category
    var ingredients: [Ingredient]
    var related: [Recipe.ID] = []
    var imageName: String? = nil
}

struct Ingredient: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var description: String

    static func fromLines(_ lines: String) -> [Ingredient] {
        lines.split(separator: "\n", omittingEmptySubsequences: true)
            .map { Ingredient(description: String($0)) }
    }
}

let builtInRecipes: [Recipe] = {
    var recipes = [
        "Apple Pie": Recipe(
            name: "Apple Pie", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: Ingredient.fromLines(applePie)),
        "Baklava": Recipe(
            name: "Baklava", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Bolo de Rolo": Recipe(
            name: "Bolo de rolo", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Chocolate Crackles": Recipe(
            name: "Chocolate crackles", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Crème Brûlée": Recipe(
            name: "Crème brûlée", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Fruit Pie Filling": Recipe(
            name: "Fruit Pie Filling", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Kanom Thong Ek": Recipe(
            name: "Kanom Thong Ek", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Mochi": Recipe(
            name: "Mochi", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Marzipan": Recipe(
            name: "Marzipan", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Pie Crust": Recipe(
            name: "Pie Crust", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: Ingredient.fromLines(pieCrust)),
        "Shortbread Biscuits": Recipe(
            name: "Shortbread Biscuits", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Tiramisu": Recipe(
            name: "Tiramisu", category: .dessert,
            ingredients: []),
        "Crêpe": Recipe(
            name: "Crêpe", category: .pancake, ingredients: []),
        "Jianbing": Recipe(
            name: "Jianbing", category: .pancake, ingredients: []),
        "American": Recipe(
            name: "American", category: .pancake, ingredients: []),
        "Dosa": Recipe(
            name: "Dosa", category: .pancake, ingredients: []),
        "Injera": Recipe(
            name: "Injera", category: .pancake, ingredients: []),
        "Acar": Recipe(
            name: "Acar", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Ambrosia": Recipe(
            name: "Ambrosia", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Bok l'hong": Recipe(
            name: "Bok l'hong", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Caprese": Recipe(
            name: "Caprese", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Ceviche": Recipe(
            name: "Ceviche", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Çoban salatası": Recipe(
            name: "Çoban salatası", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Fiambre": Recipe(
            name: "Fiambre", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Kachumbari": Recipe(
            name: "Kachumbari", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
        "Niçoise": Recipe(
            name: "Niçoise", category: .salad, ingredients: []),
    ]

    recipes["Apple Pie"]!.related = [
        recipes["Pie Crust"]!.id,
        recipes["Fruit Pie Filling"]!.id,
    ]

    recipes["Pie Crust"]!.related = [recipes["Fruit Pie Filling"]!.id]
    recipes["Fruit Pie Filling"]!.related = [recipes["Pie Crust"]!.id]

    return Array(recipes.values)
}()

let applePie = """
    ¾ cup white sugar
    2 tablespoons all-purpose flour
    ½ teaspoon ground cinnamon
    ¼ teaspoon ground nutmeg
    ½ teaspoon lemon zest
    7 cups thinly sliced apples
    2 teaspoons lemon juice
    1 tablespoon butter
    1 recipe pastry for a 9 inch double crust pie
    4 tablespoons milk
    """

let pieCrust = """
    2 ½ cups all purpose flour
    1 Tbsp. powdered sugar
    1 tsp. sea salt
    ½ cup shortening
    ½ cup butter (Cold, Cut Into Small Pieces)
    ⅓ cup cold water (Plus More As Needed)
    """

struct PushableStack_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PushableStack()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach, passing `path` as a `Binding` and setting it to `[]`, to go back to the root (Categories) view.

```
 struct RecipeDetail: View {
     @Binding var path: [Recipe]  // <--- here
     
     @EnvironmentObject private var dataModel: DataModel
     var recipe: Recipe

     var body: some View {
         Text("Recipe details go here")
             .navigationTitle(recipe.name)
         ForEach(recipe.related.compactMap { dataModel[$0] }) { related in
             NavigationLink(related.name, value: related)
         }
         // I would like to have a Button here
         Button(action: {
             // Go all the way back to the root
             path = []  // <--- here
         }) {
             Text("Go back to Categories")
         }
     }
 }
```

and call

```
   RecipeDetail(path: $path, recipe: recipe)
```

Comment: Wow, that was so easy! I had thought about doing something similar but kept thinking the call to root had to be in the original view or that I shouldn't be using a Binding. Thank you!